# Adding hints to a JQuery hangman game

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create Hangman game for my country. I have a list of random words to appear, and it's working correctly. Now I want to add hints. For example, if word is "School" selected, I want the hint to be "the place where you learn" and I don't know how to do that.

Code:

```
/*
* SPOILER ALERT! 
* WORDS FOR THE GAME ARE IN THIS FILE ;)
* Â©2014 Nate Wiley -- MIT License
Sounds from http://soundfxnow.com, and http://www.soundjay.com
Fonts from Google Fonts
*/
(function($, window, undefined){

  Hangman = {
    init: function(words){
      this.hint = $(".hint"),
      this.words = words,
      this.hm = $(".hangman"),
      this.msg = $(".message"),
      this.msgTitle = $(".title"),
      this.msgText = $(".text"),
      this.restart = $(".restart"),
      this.wrd = this.randomWord(),
      this.correct = 0,
      this.guess = $(".guess"),
      this.wrong = $(".wrong"),
      this.giveUp = $(".giveUpBtn"),
      this.wrongGuesses = [],
      this.rightGuesses = [],
      this.guessForm = $(".guessForm"),
      this.guessLetterInput = $(".guessLetter"),
      this.goodSound = new Audio("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/goodbell.mp3"),
      this.badSound = new Audio("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/bad.mp3"),
      this.winSound = new Audio("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/win.mp3"),
      this.loseSound = new Audio("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/lose.mp3"),
      /*Aww Sound Added for the 'I give up' */
      this.awwSound = new Audio ("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/131045/aww.mp3"),
      this.setup();
    },


    setup: function(){
      this.binding();
      this.sounds();
      this.showGuess(this.wrongGuesses);
      this.showWrong();

    },


    sounds: function(){  
      this.badSound.volume = .4;
      this.goodSound.volume = .4;
      this.winSound.volume = .8;
      this.loseSound.volume = .4;
      this.awwSound.volume = .8;

    },


    binding: function(){
      this.guessForm.on("submit", $.proxy(this.theGuess, this));
      this.giveUp.on("click", $.proxy(this.theAnswer, this));
      this.restart.on("click", $.proxy(this.theRestart, this));
      this.hint.on("click",$.proxy(this.hintanswer,this))
    },


    playSound: function(sound){
      this.stopSound(sound);
      this[sound].play();
    },


    stopSound: function(sound){
      this[sound].pause();
      this[sound].currentTime = 0;

    },


    theRestart: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.stopSound("winSound");
      this.stopSound("loseSound");
      this.stopSound("awwSound");
      this.reset();
    },


    theGuess: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var guess = this.guessLetterInput.val();
      if(guess.match(/[áƒ-áƒ°]/) && guess.length == 1){
        if($.inArray(guess, this.wrongGuesses) > -1 || $.inArray(guess, this.rightGuesses) > -1){
          this.playSound("badSound");
          this.guessLetterInput.val("").focus();
        }
        else if(guess) {
          var foundLetters = this.checkGuess(guess);
          if(foundLetters.length > 0){
            this.setLetters(foundLetters);
            this.playSound("goodSound");
            this.guessLetterInput.val("").focus();
          } else {
            this.wrongGuesses.push(guess);
            if(this.wrongGuesses.length == 10){
              this.lose();
            } else {
              this.showWrong(this.wrongGuesses);
              this.playSound("badSound");
            }
            this.guessLetterInput.val("").focus();
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.guessLetterInput.val("").focus();
      }
    },

    randomWord: function(){
      return this._wordData(this.words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length)] );
    },


    showGuess: function(){
      var frag = "<ul class='word'>";
      $.each(this.wrd.letters, function(key, val){
        frag += "<li data-pos='" +  key  + "' class='letter'>*</li>";
      });
      frag += "</ul>";
      this.guess.html(frag);
    },


    showWrong: function(wrongGuesses){
      if(wrongGuesses){
        var frag = "<ul class='wrongLetters'>";
        frag += "<p>áƒ“áƒáƒ¨áƒ•áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ£áƒšáƒ˜ áƒ¨áƒ”áƒªáƒ“áƒáƒ›áƒ: </p>";
        $.each(wrongGuesses, function(key, val){
          frag += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
        });
        frag += "</ul>";
      }
      else {
        frag = "";
      }

      this.wrong.html(frag);
    },



    checkGuess: function(guessedLetter){
      var _ = this;
      var found = [];
      $.each(this.wrd.letters, function(key, val){
        if(guessedLetter == val.letter.toLowerCase()){
          found.push(val);
          _.rightGuesses.push(val.letter);
        }
      });
      return found;

    },


    setLetters: function(letters){
      var _ = this;
      _.correct = _.correct += letters.length;
      $.each(letters, function(key, val){
        var letter = $("li[data-pos=" +val.pos+ "]");
        letter.html(val.letter);
        letter.addClass("correct");

        if(_.correct  == _.wrd.letters.length){
          _.win();
        }
      });
    },


    _wordData: function(word){

      return {
        letters: this._letters(word),
        word: word.toLowerCase(),
        totalLetters: word.length
      };
    },


    hideMsg: function(){
      this.msg.hide();
      this.msgTitle.hide();
      this.restart.hide();
      this.msgText.hide();
    },


    showMsg: function(){
      var _ = this;
      _.msg.show("blind", function(){
        _.msgTitle.show("bounce", "slow", function(){
          _.msgText.show("slide", function(){
            _.restart.show("fade");
          });

        });

      });
    },


    reset: function(){
      this.hideMsg();
      this.init(this.words);
      this.hm.find(".guessLetter").focus();

    },


    _letters: function(word){
      var letters = [];
      for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++){
        letters.push({
          letter: word[i],
          pos: i
        });
      }
      return letters;
    },


    rating: function(){
      var right = this.rightGuesses.length,
          wrong = this.wrongGuesses.length || 0,
          rating = {
            rating: Math.floor(( right / ( wrong + right )) * 100),
            guesses: (right + wrong)

          };
      return rating;
    },

    win: function(){
      var rating = this.rating();
      this.msgTitle.html("áƒ’áƒ˜áƒšáƒáƒªáƒáƒ•áƒ—, áƒ—áƒ¥áƒ•áƒ”áƒœ áƒ’áƒáƒ›áƒáƒ˜áƒªáƒáƒœáƒ˜áƒ—!");
      // this is messy
      this.msgText.html("áƒ—áƒ¥áƒ•áƒ”áƒœ áƒ’áƒáƒ›áƒáƒ˜áƒªáƒáƒœáƒ˜áƒ— áƒ¡áƒ˜áƒ¢áƒ§áƒ•áƒ <span class='highlight'>" + rating.guesses + "</span> áƒªáƒ“áƒáƒ¨áƒ˜!<br>áƒ¥áƒ£áƒšáƒ: <span class='highlight'>" + rating.rating + "%</span>");
      this.showMsg();
      this.playSound("winSound");

    },


    lose: function(){
      this.msgTitle.html("áƒ—áƒ¥áƒ•áƒ”áƒœ áƒ“áƒáƒ›áƒáƒ áƒªáƒ®áƒ“áƒ˜áƒ—.. áƒ¡áƒ˜áƒ¢áƒ§áƒ•áƒ áƒ˜áƒ§áƒ <span class='highlight'>"+ this.wrd.word +"</span>");
      this.msgText.html("áƒáƒ  áƒ˜áƒœáƒ”áƒ áƒ•áƒ˜áƒ£áƒšáƒáƒ—, áƒ¨áƒ”áƒ›áƒ“áƒ”áƒ’áƒ¨áƒ˜ áƒ’áƒáƒ›áƒáƒ˜áƒªáƒœáƒáƒ‘áƒ—!");
      this.showMsg();
      this.playSound("loseSound");
    },
   /*theAnswer() initiated when you give up*/
    theAnswer: function(){
       var answer = this.wrd.word;
       this.msgTitle.html("áƒáƒ°áƒ°.. áƒ¨áƒ”áƒœ áƒ“áƒáƒœáƒ”áƒ‘áƒ“áƒ˜!");
      this.msgText.html(" áƒ¡áƒ˜áƒ¢áƒ§áƒ•áƒ áƒ˜áƒ§áƒ  <span class='highlight'>"+ this.wrd.word +"</span>");                 
       this.showMsg();
       this.playSound("awwSound");
    },
  hintanswer: function() {
  var answer = this.wrd.word;
  this,msgTitle.html("áƒ«áƒáƒšáƒ˜áƒáƒœ áƒáƒ“áƒ•áƒ˜áƒšáƒ˜áƒ!");
  this.showMsg();
  },
  };

  var wordList = ["áƒ¡áƒ™áƒáƒšáƒ", "áƒ™áƒ•áƒ”áƒ áƒªáƒ®áƒ˜", "áƒ™áƒáƒ áƒ¢áƒáƒ¤áƒ˜áƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒ£áƒ¡áƒ˜áƒ™áƒ", "áƒ›áƒáƒœáƒ¥áƒáƒœáƒ", "áƒ™áƒáƒ›áƒžáƒ˜áƒ£áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ áƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒ–áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ£áƒ›áƒ–áƒ˜áƒ áƒ", "áƒ¤áƒáƒ áƒ¢áƒ”áƒžáƒ˜áƒáƒœáƒ", "áƒ¡áƒáƒ—áƒšáƒ”áƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ¬áƒ˜áƒ’áƒœáƒ˜", "áƒ’áƒáƒ¡áƒáƒ¦áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ˜", "áƒ¢áƒ”áƒšáƒ”áƒ•áƒ˜áƒ–áƒáƒ áƒ˜", "áƒ°áƒáƒ™áƒ”áƒ áƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒáƒ£áƒ¡áƒ˜", "áƒ™áƒšáƒáƒ•áƒ˜áƒáƒ¢áƒ£áƒ áƒ", "áƒ•áƒ”áƒ¤áƒ®áƒ˜áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒ§áƒáƒáƒ¡áƒáƒœáƒ˜", "áƒ™áƒáƒ›áƒáƒ—áƒ”áƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ‘áƒ˜áƒšáƒ˜áƒáƒ áƒ“áƒ˜", "áƒ—áƒ”áƒáƒ¢áƒ áƒ˜", "áƒ áƒ”áƒ™áƒšáƒáƒ›áƒ", "áƒ¢áƒ§áƒšáƒáƒžáƒ˜", "áƒ¡áƒ£áƒ áƒáƒ—áƒ˜", "áƒ©áƒ˜áƒšáƒ˜áƒ›áƒ˜", "áƒ—áƒ•áƒáƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ—áƒáƒ•áƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒ£áƒ®áƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ¤áƒáƒ áƒ“áƒ", "áƒ¬áƒ™áƒšáƒ˜áƒžáƒ£áƒ áƒ¢áƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒáƒœáƒ“áƒáƒ áƒ˜áƒœáƒ˜", "áƒáƒ¡áƒ™áƒáƒ áƒ˜", "áƒžáƒ”áƒžáƒ”áƒšáƒ", "áƒšáƒáƒ§áƒ", "áƒ¯áƒáƒ áƒ—áƒ˜", "áƒáƒ¤áƒáƒ¤áƒ˜", "áƒ™áƒáƒ™áƒáƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ™áƒ”áƒ áƒ«áƒ˜", "áƒ”áƒ›áƒ˜áƒ’áƒ áƒáƒœáƒ¢áƒ˜", "áƒ¡áƒ™áƒáƒ›áƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒ”áƒ áƒ¥áƒáƒœáƒ˜", "áƒ•áƒáƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ®áƒáƒ áƒ—áƒ£áƒ›áƒ˜", "áƒ“áƒáƒ—áƒ•áƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒ”áƒšáƒ", "áƒ–áƒáƒ–áƒ£áƒœáƒ", "áƒ•áƒ”áƒ¤áƒ®áƒ•áƒ˜", "áƒ•áƒ”áƒ áƒ«áƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒáƒ›áƒáƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ¡áƒ£áƒ¤áƒ áƒ", "áƒ¢áƒ§áƒ”áƒ›áƒáƒšáƒ˜", "áƒšáƒáƒ’áƒ˜áƒœáƒ˜", "áƒ¢áƒ”áƒšáƒ”áƒ¤áƒáƒœáƒ˜", "áƒ¥áƒáƒ áƒ¬áƒ˜áƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ¥áƒáƒ áƒ˜", "áƒ’áƒ–áƒ", "áƒœáƒáƒ«áƒ•áƒ˜áƒ¡áƒ®áƒ”", "áƒ‘áƒ”áƒ°áƒ”áƒ›áƒáƒ¢áƒ˜", "áƒ¡áƒáƒ áƒ“áƒáƒ¤áƒ˜", "áƒšáƒáƒ›áƒ˜", "áƒáƒ áƒ¬áƒ˜áƒ•áƒ˜", "áƒáƒ”áƒ áƒáƒžáƒáƒ áƒ¢áƒ˜", "áƒ°áƒáƒ›áƒáƒ™áƒ˜", "áƒ‘áƒ£áƒ áƒ—áƒ˜", "áƒ¥áƒáƒ—áƒáƒ›áƒ˜", "áƒ–áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ áƒ", "áƒ°áƒ˜áƒ“áƒ áƒáƒ”áƒšáƒ”áƒ¥áƒ¢áƒ áƒáƒ¡áƒáƒ“áƒ’áƒ£áƒ áƒ˜", "áƒ¡áƒáƒ¦áƒ”áƒ‘áƒáƒ•áƒ˜", "áƒáƒ áƒ¥áƒ˜áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ¥áƒ¢áƒáƒ áƒ˜", "áƒ®áƒáƒ®áƒ", "áƒ—áƒ˜áƒ—áƒ˜", "áƒ­áƒ áƒ˜áƒ­áƒ˜áƒœáƒ", "áƒ—áƒáƒ›áƒ‘áƒáƒ¥áƒ", "áƒšáƒ£áƒ“áƒ˜", "áƒ¨áƒáƒ£áƒ áƒ›áƒ", "áƒ¡áƒáƒ¤áƒ”áƒ—áƒ¥áƒ”áƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ›áƒ”áƒ¢áƒ áƒ", "áƒ¥áƒáƒ áƒ˜áƒ¨áƒ®áƒáƒšáƒ˜", "áƒ áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒáƒ áƒáƒœáƒ˜"];
  var engword = ["book","room","home","table","garbage","blind","fear","number","patent","lose","basketball"];
  Hangman.init(wordList);

})(jQuery, window);
```

Link to code: http://331542.esy.es/game/js/index.js

How can I add the hints to this code?

Comment: First reduce your problem down to the minimum code required (there's no need for the vast majority of your posted code). The question you're really asking, I think, is "*how can I associate details of a given word! or problem, together in javascript?*" The answer? Use an an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would more than likely want to incorporate them into your `wordList` and `engWord` data objects. Perhaps convert them into actual objects in case you need to add any other data to them (difficulty, etc)

```
var wordList [
  { word: "book", hint: "this is my book hint" },
  { word: "room", hint: "this is my room hint" }
];
```

You would then have to change your code that uses the word object.

```
randomWord: function(){
  return this._wordData(this.words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length)].word );
},
```

Notice the addition of the property of your new objects `.word`. You would use the same approach for hints anywhere you needed to access `this.words[n].hint`.

I would also take a long look into Javascript Object Orientated Programming. Applying the fundamentals of OOP to your Hangman game would go a very long way.

Some examples:

http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter8.html

http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

**Updated**
Your hintanswer should look something like this.

```
hintanswer: function() {
  var hint = this.wrd.hint;
  this.msgTitle.html(hint);
  this.showMsg();
}
```

Comment: Don boots, my cute ! wordlist and randomword functions are working finaly now,  and can u please tell me how let hint to be appeared on the website please. I know i  m a poor with js but really last ask ... PS i LOVE you

Comment: bro, i have created   >  this.hint = $(".hint"),  then in random : randomWord: function(){
  return this._wordData(this.words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length)].word );
},  then 

hintanswer: function() {
  var hint = this.wrd.hint;
  this.msgTitle.html(hint);
  this.showMsg();
}
And do I have to write in html anything?  I have ccreated in html  <button type="submit" class="hint">sss</button>

Comment: and hint wont show up, idk why really getting angry :(:(:( if u have skype or fb or so please tell me to contact you I beg you really

Comment: Try this for randomWord: `randomWord: function(){ return this._wordData(this.words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length)]); }` We want to set your _wordData to the word **object**, you are currently setting it to the word **property** of the **object**.

Comment: So I need to create wordData for hint or ?

Comment: In `randomWord`, `this._wordData` is now set to an object. When you reference `this.wrd`, you would can now access it's available properties. For example `this.wrd.word` or `this.wrd.hint`

Comment: Yes bro, I understand it , but for example look here : 
randomWord: function(){
      return this._wordData(this.words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length)].word );
    },

then  to test it  this.hint = $ (".hint"),
and in html  : <button class="hint"> TEST </html>
then in js :  this.hint.on("click",$.proxy(this.hintanswer, this));
and then hintanswer function { var hint = this.wrd.hint , alert(hint) , and it shows as udefined word. but if I say this.wrd.word its says a word correctly

Comment: You need to remove the `.word` from return of your `randomWord` function so you are returning `this._wordData(this.words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length)]);` instead of `this._wordData(this.words[ Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length)].word);`

Comment: When I delete .word  the words won't be appeared on the web

Comment: Post your solution to a www.jsfiddle.com or www.codepen.io and we can troubleshoot it there.

Comment: Ok Boots, I am gonna do that right now <3 with the same question okey? hope u will be there aswell my bro :D <3

Comment: but www.jsfiddle.com   DOES  NOT WORK :(

Comment: http://codepen.io/samxo/details/dPeVdP/   
 thats my Code in CodepEn, I am searching for FORUM

Comment: That codepen is good enough to work with. Can you change the words in the HTML to English?

Comment: YES YES < just a secund !

Comment: Don Boots any news? <3

Comment: 10x a LOT Don boots. I LOVE YOU MAN ! <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Comment: Accept this as answer!

Comment: What you mean? howto do that

Comment: Ah i did that, ty a lot again !